# I rendered a 2000+ frame AVI movie with Blender Render and it corrupted, why?

Tags: rendering, video

I wanted to make a movie showing of a 3d model, 2250 frames long, Blender Render, AVI, but after I rendered it it won't open, and when I open it in After Effects only 7 seconds is available. Why is this? Is there some setting that one can change to render it without it getting corrupted. There was nothing happening, it was running alone, no errors.

Don't really know what screenshots I could add, it just won't open any media player and is always just 7 seconds long in editing programs. If there's a question that needs to be answered to solve this, I'll try my best to answer it. I'm sorry if it's anything obvious, but I've never done a render as long as this so I'm maybe doing something wrong, I don't know..

EDIT: Tried the video editor in Blender. File still corrupted

Comment: Things can go wrong during rendering - sometimes frames are dropped - and that's why it considered best practice to render stills and then compile them into animations later. Compiling video's with stills goes really quick, and if you notice you have one dropped / corrupted still frame to re-render, is not a train smash...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry to hear about your file; that can certainly be frustrating. I'm not sure why it became corrupted, but the best practice is always to render an image sequence. That way, if something goes wrong you can resume from where you left off. Plus, you can also open the sequence in After Effects (or any program that supports image sequences, including Blender) and re-export as an video file of your choice, if you need it to be one contiguous file. [See this video as an example.](https://youtu.be/oWmsUIbxQUk) I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with animations, and it was 'corrupt' in every app I tried to do anything with it, except VLC. I opened it in VLC, it opened fine, and then exported as a different format (avi > mp4) and now it's working in all the apps I use just fine. Maybe it's just a weird issue with how blender exports but that might help you move forward with it.